# Emeditor右クリックメニュー「EmEditorでファイルから検索」を非表示にしたい

Tags: emeditor

## 質問

添付画像のメニューを非表示にしたいです。
どの様にすればよいでしょうか？

## 環境

- EmEditor Professional (64Bit) Version 22.2.10
- Windows 11 64 Bit 21H2 (Build 22000.1455)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ツール] メニューから [カスタマイズ] を選択し、[ショートカット] ページを選択し、[エクスプローラのコンテキスト メニューにショートカットを追加] チェック ボックスをクリアします。もしコンピューター毎にインストールされているため、このチェック ボックスが無効になっていてチェックできない場合には、一度、EmEditor をアンインストールしてください。再びインストールする際、[カスタム] インストールを選択すると、コンテキスト メニューを無効にすることができます。

引用先: [エクスプローラで右クリックした時に表示されるコンテキスト メニューに EMEDITOR が表示されないようにするには、どうしたらいいですか?](https://jp.emeditor.com/faq/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB-faq/%E3%82%A8%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A9%E3%81%A7%E5%8F%B3%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B/)

Comment: おっしゃる通りの操作をすると消す事ができました。
しかし、ファイルの右クリックのメニューも消えてしまいました。
フォルダ内を右クリックした時の「EmEditorでファイルから検索」だけを非表示にする事は可能ですか？
拡張子のtsファイルは「TypeScriptのts」と「動画ファイルのts」2つの意味があるのでファイルの右クリックメニューは残したいです。

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqMGj.png

Comment: EmEditor側の設定のチェックボックスを入れたまま、以下レジストリを削除すると解決しました。公式の解決方法では無く自己責任ですが取り急ぎ解決はしました。"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\EmEditor"